# The airbag light is on in my 2012 Chevy Silverado my car hasn't been in an accident

Tags: warning-light, supplemental-restraint-system

[image: 2012 Chevrolet Silverado Dash]

My airbag light is on in my 2012 Chevrolet Silverado.  How do I reset it? The vehicle has not been in an accident.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As Solar Mike stated, you really need to have the codes read to figure out what's going on. One of the things which go wrong with the Silverado SRS is the front sensors which are located directly under the radiator (on the bottom side of the core support). You won't know if this is right unless you get the codes read.

Answer (score 2):

The air-bag system has detected a fault, so you need to get the codes read to ascertain the fault or take it in to a service shop where they will read the codes and tell you what needs doing.

At the moment you have no idea whether the system will protect you in an accident.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://www.doityourself.com/stry/how-to-reset-an-airbag-light) it's pretty easy, but you'd never guess it.  :)

1. **Plug in all dash components:** If there are any dash components unplugged (ie, speedometer, gas light, etc.), you'll have to plug them in before starting.  This is probably not an issue in your case; it's more important if the vehicle was in an accident and some components were unplugged for repairs.
2. **Turn ignition position to on.**
3. **Wait for airbag light to turn off:** It should turn off 7 seconds after turning the key, after which you will have 1 second to turn the ignition position to off.
4. **Turn ignition back on:** After 3 seconds, turn the ignition back on.
5. **Repeat twice.**

Hope it helps!